# Laziness: "Pereza" vs "flojera"

Tags: vocabulario

Both mean "laziness" according to the dictionary. Is there any difference in usage? Regional preference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that `flojera` mainly refers to a physical aspect ("flojo"= sin fuerza). I have always used `pereza` for laziness and `flojera` to a hindrance to physical work (maybe because you are feeling down the weather or something similar, you feel too weak or are exhausted). So to me `flojera` means something closer to "weakness" or "exhaustion" than an unwillingness to do something.

Comment: Is flojedad any different from flojero?

Comment: @AmitSchandillia, was that a typo? I have never heard "flojer**o**". The proper adjetive would be "fojo/floja" to refer so somebody "Luis es un _flojo_. No puede levantar ni 5 kilos". Flojer**a** would be a synonym of "flojedad", and at least in Spain, would be more used than "flojedad". "Me ha entrado la flojera (cansancio)" is OK, but instead of "flojedad" people would use "debilidad": "Es una _debilidad_ (instead of _flojedad_) de este material" .

Comment: Ohh yes that was a typo...I meant flojera. Sorry.

Comment: @AmitSchandillia, no worries! I just didn't know if it was a typo or you had a question about a declination of the word, so I tried to cover as much as I could.

Answer (score 3):

It's also a regional preference. For example in Argentina nobody would say 'flojera', but we do know the meaning (it's very common to hear it in movies or series dubbed in México)

Comment: And there´s an even more colloquial way to say it in México: "hueva".

Answer (score 2):

- **Perezoso** is very clear: negligente, tardo, lento, descuidado, flojo
- **Flojo** is regional, and could be interpreted as lazy, with no firm convictions, or even gay in Cuba
- **Huevón** another regional, and vulgar expression. could be interpreted as lazy or courageous, or an idiot (depends on the region), but referring to a lazy person, it is more graphical. *Este es un huevonazo!*